# How do I align text and buttons on the same line?

Tags: html, css, slider

When the screen width is less than 479px, I want the text to be under the slider. Right now when I resize my browser to < 479px, one of the text div is on top of the slider and the other is on the bottom.

Here's the testing link: http://chemistry2014.tw/

What I want it to look like:

[image]

Comment: In HTML put text after slider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the way you have set your html. If you have the option of changing the html markup, the best solution is to relocate the div and put it after the slider form. The alternative would be to `absolute` position the element with a top margin, at the correct screen size.

Example CSS:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px)
   .D-answer {
      margin-top: 40px;
      position: absolute;
      // rest of CSS code
```

**Edited**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .container{ width: 300px; }  <----------------- add this
    h4 {text-align:center; margin-left:0px;}
    .D-answer {margin-left:0px;}
    .A-answer {margin-right:0px;}
}
```

Comment: Ok so sorry to bother you but can you help me out again? Everything on http://chemistry2014.tw/ works fine in Chrome on my computer but it's messed up on my phone and safari. The weird part is it's only messed up when the browser is less than 767px. I looked at my media queries but nothing seems wrong.

Comment: It is because your mobile brwoser is not recognizing your `.container` media query. See my edited answer.